# Tortoise: diff between local uncommitted version and last repo version of a file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, repository, diff

We are three of us working on the same project, at the same time.
It can occur we need to modify the same file to perform different tasks (bug-fixings or enhancements), but we use the svn repo only to track online (www) changes, while we keep our own changes in local during development.

Is there a way, in TortoiseSVN, to compare my local, modified version of a file and the latest on the repo (i.e. the www version)?

Using the 'diff' option from the contextual menu is not the solution, because it compares my working copy and the working base I started from, not the latest on the repo (probably committed by a colleague of mine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Check-For-Modifications dialog.
Push the `Check Repository` button. That will then show you the files that were modified and committed to the repository, but which you haven't updated to your working copy yet.

Right-clicking on such files gives you the option to do that diff.

Or just use the log dialog and do the diff there.

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN has an option in the contextual menu: *check for modifications*, maybe this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ghost copy of your source available you can use any diff tool to compare the 'live' source with what you currently have.

I think it is possible to set up ghost copies using svn.